# How to set different start page for every User in Magento Admin Panel?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show different start up page for each admin users. So I can do it?

Eg. Supper User's start up is 'Dashboard'

```
Admin User user1's  start up page will be 'sales'

Admin User user2's  start up page will be 'customer'
```

how i can do it? please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have many users, if not, you can just go to  System menu>Configuration>Admin>Startup Page for each admin user.

Comment: Its is global attribute. so How can we differentiate it for every admin user? If anybody know about please share with us...

Comment: Can yo write a module, you will have to override some core functionallity through a module to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be older and may be originally asked for Magento 1 but in case someone still having same question for Magento 2 then below extension should help to solve the situation

https://redchamps.com/admin-user-specific-startup-page-magento-2-extension.html

Please note that this is a paid extension & I belong to the company who developed it.